# How to verify the signature of an LTPA 1 token

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, ltpa

Does anyone know how to verify the signature part of a decrypted LTPA token?

I have the keys exported from my WPE8 server, and properly decoded the LTPA token so I see the user data, expiration and signature.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the LTPA token format is an IBM standard. As you probably have noticed there are a few examples on how to decrypt the token (but none of the ones I've seen include verifying the signature) but even that is not very safe as it is an IBM standard and they have not yet published any public APIs to use the LTPA at all.

I did a lot of work trying to achieve SSO between the WP server we had and other non-WebSphere servers and we found that the easiest was to create our own token in Login Filters.